# How to get date from one table and insert into another table

Tags: sql-server

I used following queries to get date from one table and insert into another table.

```
INSERT INTO InstallmentPaymentHistory 
VALUES('DateSold')

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), s.DateSold, 113) AS DateSold  
FROM SalesInvoice s 
WHERE s.SalesInvoiceID = 9;
```

but I get an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

I have also tried

```
INSERT INTO InstallmentPaymentHistory 
VALUES('YYYY.MM.DD')  

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), s.DateSold, 113) AS DateSold  
FROM SalesInvoice s 
WHERE s.SalesInvoiceID = 9;
```

But I get the same error.

Table #1

```
SalesInvoiceID  CustomerID   SoldDate       TotalBill
-------------------------------------------------------     
1                3840        2018.03.22      20000
2                4581        2018.04.11      80000
3                4420        2018.05.13      60000
```

Table # 2

```
InstallmentPaymentID    SalesInvoiceID  InstallmentNo     DueDate PaymentDdate
---------------------------------------------------------------                 
1                     2                 1            2018.03.22  2018.3.22
2                     2                 2            2018.04.11  2018.3.22
3                     2                 3            2018.05.13  2018.3.22
```

Comment: Your `INSERT` can *either* be something like `INSERT INTO Table(list-of-columns) VALUES (list-of-values)`, **or** it can be `INSERT INTO Table(list-of-columns) SELECT list-of-columns FROM .... WHERE ....` - but I really don't understand what you're trying to do here - some `VALUES`, but also a  `SELECT` - are you expecting both to provide values for the `INSERT` ?? That definitely won't work!

Comment: I will get values from front end GUI from user, but DueDate  column ( table # 2) will get value from SoldDate column(Table # 1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not entirely clear what you're trying to do with those commands......

If you want to use the `SELECT`, combined with some fixed values, then you should use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.InstallmentPaymentHistory (specify-the-list-of-columns-here!)
    SELECT 
        -- provide the fixed values here, first
        11, 9, 2, 'DateSold', '20180306', 6000,
        -- then the "calculated/converted" value from your other table
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), s.DateSold, 113) 
    FROM 
        dbo.SalesInvoice s 
    WHERE 
        s.SalesInvoiceID = 9;
```

Also: it's not clear from your post whether the date string `2018.3.6` refers to the **3rd of June** or the **6th of March** - but I'd recommend to **always** use the adapted ISO-8601 format, which is `YYYYMMDD` (*without* any dashes or anything!).

So for 6th of March, use `20180306`, and for 3rd of June use `20180603`

Comment: @shakeelahmad: updated my response - your date formatting is very unusual - see my comment and pick the "correct" value for you

Comment: my Date format is YYYY.MM.DD i have edited my question for easy understanding that what i want

Comment: I'm trying to find the graceful way, not to cast the datetime into a string. Because as a string, the db has to parse it again. Then there is no way to pass a datetime with its original data form?